# Why don't we see/feel charged particles, penetrating our brains/retina?

Tags: biology, perception, cosmic-rays

If we see tracks in bubble or Wilson chamber, it means that particles are everywhere and can leave tracks in gases and liquids. They can also penetrate concrete of the building levels in the lab. So they definitely penetrate our brains, retina, optic nerve and so on. But why don't we see any flashes or glitches, related to these particles? I heard astronautes can see something, but why doesn't it comnon down here? Do we have some physiological protection for this?

Comment: But we do! See https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspl.1903.0067

Comment: Note that we here on earth are protected by earths magnetic field, so comparing our experiences to those who don't have such protection is a little problematic.

Comment: Ahhh, yes, the early 20th century when you could just have multiple milligrams of radium and write papers about irradiating yourself.

Comment: You may wish to estimate the flux of these particles hitting the retina, and compare to the flux of photons in a bright room, or the dark current (thermally activated photoreceptors) of the eyes in the absence of light.

Comment: @KyleKanos please consider cloud chamber table experiments; they prove that some particles pass through magnetic field

Comment: @RaghuParthasarathy I can see, that the volume of my brain is approximetely the same, that is of cloud chamber, so I should have several particles per second penetrating content of my scull

Comment: @Dims I didn't intend that to mean the flux of cosmic ray particles is zero on earth, just that it is strongly reduced when compared to outside

Comment: @KyleKanos so, if charged particle travels across our brains does it make ionisation along the way? If it does, then does it cause neural imlulses to apper/modify? If it does, then why don't we feel it? Do we have some suppression circuitry for this, or it is just wrong reasoning?